# Google Earth Engine: mapping over feature collection returns image collection of unknown elements

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a variable that is a function that returns an image collection of the monthly mode from google's dynamic world.  This works great.

I'm attempting to use this while mapping over a feature collection.  It works but the image collections returned appears to be empty.  Image collection of unknown elements.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e997fa4ee21cdb2474d21ea640b93fea

In the above code I'm printing out the initial variable then my attempt at mapping over the feature collection.  I want to get the initial output for each feature in the feature collection.

Where am I going wrong?

In the example I have 3 features.  Each feature should have 12 images (1 for each month).  I can flatten the output and I do correctly get 36 images that appear as they should.  I can add a property that associates each image with the feature using the feature id then later filter by that property.  This works
https://code.earthengine.google.com/a28fe8fb412d738605c4d4d13208bcee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is that if you `map` a particular function to a `ee.FeatureCollection`, the expected output will be also be a `ee.FeatureColletion`. In this case, the intended output should be an `ee.ImageCollection`, instead. One trick to avoid this is to map over a `ee.List` which returns a `ee.List` which you can easily convert it to any type of object you desire.

```
// Try to do the same as above but by feature
var byFeature = function(index){
  // Select features one by one according to system:index
  var ft = geometry.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index',ee.String(index)))
                   .first();
  // Removed the ImageCollection.fromImages so everything is stored as elements of a list
  var byMonth = months.map(function (m) {
          return dwCol.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                      .mode()
                      .set('month', m)
                      .clip(ft);
  });  
  return byMonth;
};

print(geometry);

// Get the system:index property as a list
var list = geometry.aggregate_array('system:index');
print(list);

// Map over the system:index list
var all = list.map(byFeature);
print(all);

// Flatten the list of lists into a list of images and convert to ImageCollection
var resul = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(all.flatten());
print(resul);

// Add the first image to confirm that the output is correct
Map.addLayer(resul.first(), {}, 'first');
```